# How to hide year in calender jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am using this to hide year in calender but it hides only the year in current months. the following is the coffee script.

```
$("#contact_date_of_birth").datepicker().on "show", (ev) ->
  $("span#span-year").hide()
```

what to do to hide year in all months. Regards

Comment: you can set `dateFormat` that just show date and month.

Comment: @DipeshParmar.... not working!

Comment: well what you can do is...dynamically append dateFormat of date selection so when selected date is from current month use date format to date and month else show date month and year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by adding this css

```
.ui-datepicker-year { display:none }
```

Comment: this is not what i want... my calender show the current month without year and reemaining months with year

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#contact_date_of_birth").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm' });
```

Comment: my querry hide the year but only for current month not at all.